# How to fix wrong proxy redirection from sub path from React.js using React Router?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, express

I'm making a multi-pages app with React Router and I'm using Node for the backend. 
Node is working on the port 3000 and React on the port 3001.
I have set up a proxy in package.json of the front-end(React).
My API is reachable on localhost:3000/api/
So my get or post from the frontend(port:3001) with axios look like this:

```
axios.post('api/login/',{data........})
```

It is working perfectly from a parent path like /item or /example
http://localhost:3001/xxxxxx/ ...
I can reach my /api/login on port 3000.

But from a subpath like http://localhost:3001/another/ex/ or http://localhost:3001/xxxxxx/example/ ... I see in the console the get or post request is sent to http://localhost:3001/xxxxxx/example/api/login
In those cases, the proxy doesn't redirect properly.

I have found the solution to avoid sub path but I would like to know what exactly is happening and what is the solutions?

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<Router history={history}>
<NavBar history={history} refresh={this.state.refresh}/> 
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <MainPage history= 
{history} />}/>

<Route exact path="/item" history={history} component= 
{ComponentX1} />

<Route exact path="/example" history={history} component= 
{ComponentX2} />

<Route exact path='/another/ex' history={history} component= 
{ComponentY1}/>

<Route exact path='/xxxxxx/example' history={history} component=    
{ComponentY2}/>

</Switch>
<Footer/>
</Router>
```

I would like to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use must have the path as such.

```
axios.post("/api/login", { ...data }) // Included '/' at the beginning
```

Also, check if proxy in **package.json** is as such

```
...
proxy: 'http://localhost:3000' // not '/' at end.
...
```

If you have any doubts ping me in comments.

Comment: Hi @Naveen Vignesh. Thanks for having taken the time to answer. The proxy is set correctly as it is working for example with api/login because I make the call from localhost:3001/login on my frontend but if for example, I would like to reach the same point of the API but from user/login then my frontend try to reach: localhost:3001/user/login/api/login and not localhost:3000/api/login, in that case, the proxy seems not working.

Comment: You need the leading slash in your axios call, as @Naveen pointed out. Change `axios.post('api/login/',{data........})` to `axios.post('/api/login/',{data........})`. This will fix the problem with it adding the sub-path to your api call.

Comment: @BrandonMitchell This will fix the problem but what is the reason behind it.I would like to know what exactly is happening there and after adding the slash its working.Why?

Comment: "// Included '/' at the beginning." This line saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

I was using **next.config.js** to handle my proxy to my API server. and I was facing the same error. Because my API routes were like `http://172.17.19.79:8000/api/job/`  so I changed my **next.config.js** to code bellow:

```
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [{
            source: '/api/:path*',
            destination: 'http://localhost:8000/api/:path*/'
        }]
    }
}
```