# React app proxy not working when <Route> contains url parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a create react app talking to an express server via a proxy
The proxy works when I post from most components but if that component is rendered through a route containing a url parameter the request url is changed to something that doesn't exist and results in a 404

My express server endpoint (listening on port 5000)

```
registrationRouter.post('/api/create-account' function (req, res) {

        return res.status(200);

});
```

This can be curled successfully

This is called from a react component form which has the method

```
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { hash } = this.props.match.params;
     axios.post( api/create-account, {hash:hash});
    };
```

The Route contains;

```
<Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
     {/*<Route path='/create-account/:hash' component={CreateAccountForm}/>*/} 
request is sent to create-account/api/create-account resulting in 404
        <Route path='/create-account' component={CreateAccountForm}/> 
request is sent to /api/create-account )resulting in 200
        <Route path='/' component={Home}/>
</Switch>
```

proxy defined in package.json as

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

Prior to adding the proxy this was all working fine (Hard coding the post urls to localhost:5000/api/create-account of course)

This has only started happening since I introduced the proxy.

What am I doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out myself.

Answer was here

[How to fix wrong proxy redirection from sub path from React.js using React Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55907518/how-to-fix-wrong-proxy-redirection-from-sub-path-from-react-js-using-react-route).

I needed the leading slash added to my post request

```
 handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { hash } = this.props.match.params;
     axios.post( api/create-account, {hash:hash});
    };
```